# ¿Cómo puedo transladar datos especificos de un vector a uno nuevo?

Tags: java

me encuentro realizando un ejercicio de vectores lo cuál me pide ingresar N de números (edades) y detectar cuántos son mayores de 18.
Luego de ello me pide que esos datos entren a un nueva lista de vectores y se imprima por consola.

Aquí les muestro mi código...

```
Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Variables
    int edades[], n, mayoredad=0;      
    //Datos
    System.out.print("Ingrese (N) de edades: ");
    n =  lectura.nextInt();
    edades = new int[n];
    //Lectura del teclado de los datos - vector
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.print("Ingrese la edad para la posición "+i+" : ");
        edades[i] = lectura.nextInt();
    }
    //Cálculos - Reconocer los números almacenados
    for(int i=0; i< edades.length; i++){
        if(edades[i]>=18)
        mayoredad++; 
    }
    System.out.println("Total de mayores: "+mayoredad);
```

Requiero un ejemplo o cómo se realiza el translado de todos los números mayores a un nuevo vector, ya que para imprimirlos en pantalla podría utilizar:

```
//Mostrando en pantalla los elementos del vector
    System.out.println("\nLos mayores de edad son: ");
    for(int indice=0; indice<n; indice++){
        System.out.println(edades[indice]);
```

Comment: Instancia el nuevo vector, recorres el vector inicial y, por cada elemento que cumpla la condición, lo añades al nuevo y llevas una variable que se incremente sólo cuando hay adición de un nuevo elemento, con eso sabes en qué posición ubicarlo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

luego de haber conseguido la cantidad de edad mayor o igual a 18,puedes declarar un nuevo array

```
int [] arrayMayores=new int[mayoredad];
```

y hacer uso de la misma evaluación en la que conseguiste ese valor

```
    int j=0;
      for(int i=0; i< edades.length; i++){
// si la edad es mayor que 18 j aumentara la posicion para que no te lance un arrayException
            if(edades[i]>=18){
            arrayMayores[j]=edades[i]; 
            j++;
        }
     }
    
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayMayores));
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver tu tema vas a tener que definir otro vector (justo a lado de donde defines `int edades []` en ese otro vector vas a meter los valores ingresados mayores de 18 años, entonces: cuando estés en tu ciclo `For` para recorrer el vector ingresado aprovecha que ya estás comparando los valores y cuando la condición `edades[i]>=18` se cumpla entonces vas a meter ese valor comparado en el vector de datos mayores a 18 de la siguiente manera `mayores.push(edades[i]);`
como verás usé el método push(), si estás empezando en Java te recomiendo ver la documentación de este método: [Método push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

espero que mi respuesta te sirva.

Comment: El metodo ``push`` propiamente como función que sirve para añadir elemento al final de un vector no existe en java, probablemente te estas equivocando con JavaScript

Comment: tienes razón es para javascript, me equivoqué

Answer (score 0):

La desventaja de usar vectores es que se debe conocer la longitud del mismo, para el caso de tu ejercicio tendrías que usar la variable `mayorEdad` para inicializar el tamaño del nuevo vector donde se almacená los valores que sean mayores o iguales que 18, por ello es mejor usar [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) donde no es necesario conocer la longitud del vector.
Después de la lectura de datos iría el siguiente código

```
ArrayList<Integer> mayores= new ArrayList<>();
//Cálculos - Reconocer los números mayor o igual que 18       
for(int i=0; i< edades.length; i++){   
      if(edades[i]>=18) mayores.add(edades[i]);                
}

//conocer el tamaño del ArrayList
System.out.println("Total de mayores: "+mayores.size());

//Mostrando los valores del ArrayList
System.out.println(mayores.toString());
```